# Can you suggest any tool to review an existing code base effectively?

Tags: code-review

We have a large part in our code base that was never reviewed and has a lot of flaws. As every tool I know only allows code review by pull request, is there any tool to review an existing code base, so that we can comment on every line?

Comment: Crucible, from Atlassian.

Comment: Not sure who voted this as off-topic, but I think code reviews and code analyses is a core part of quality assurance.

Answer (score 2):

[Crucible](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible) (like user246 suggested) seems like a tool which has the functionality you are looking for. I have used it in the past to review commits and not pull requests. I think you can also assign parts of code.

Alternatively you can have a look at the open-source [Review Board which supports multiple ways to create reviews, from commits, hooks or even dragging files](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/users/review-requests/creating/). There are more alternatives: http://alternativeto.net/software/crucible/

**Code quality** can also be viewed/measured with a static code analyses tool like [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/):

> **SonarQube**: Put your technical debt under control

This might result in which parts might need reviews and or refactoring.